# Passing a variables as a default parameters in function c++

Tags: c++, function, default-value

Why Doesnt C++ allow This

```
void insertData (T data1,Tree<T> *tree=TreeTop);
```

Passing A Value As a Default Parameter is allowed but why not a variable as a default paramaeter....??

```
class BinaryTree
{
    private :

    Tree<T> *TreeTop;
    unsigned int numberOfElements;

    public :
            void insertData (T data1,Tree<T> *tree=TreeTop);
            // Only Prototype For Question Purpose
    }
```

Comment: yep the same doubt..!! Dint Find On Searching..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make an overload like this:

```
void insertData(T data1) {
    insertData(data1, TreeTop);
}

void insertData(T data1, Tree<T> *tree) {
    // Code
}
```

Comment: yeah i did the same only...just wanted to know what technical difficulties does the compiler faces to pass a variable as a default argument...

Answer (score 0):

This will work if you make TreeTop static:

```
class BinaryTree
{
    private :

    static Tree<T> *TreeTop;
    unsigned int numberOfElements;

    public :
            void insertData (T data1,Tree<T> *tree=TreeTop);

}
```

In that case, it will be a class-level default for the "insertData" method call.  If you want an instance-level default, you will have to instead do something like

```
class BinaryTree
{
    private :

    Tree<T> *TreeTop;
    unsigned int numberOfElements;

    public :
            void insertData (T data1,Tree<T> *tree=NULL);

}
```

Then, in your implementation, do

```
public void BinaryTree::insertData(T data1, Tree<T> *tree)
{
    if (tree==null) tree=TreeTop;
    ...
}
```

Comment: you mean `nullptr` (or `NULL` for C++03) instead of `null`.

Comment: It assumes that `nullptr` is not a *valid* input.

Comment: @Jarod42 - Yep, I've got C# on the brain ~ corrected.  Also correct on second point - assumes null is not valid input.  If null is valid, then previous poster's overload approach will get it.